# git rebase from git-svn bridge

Tags: git, git-svn

I've got a git repo that imported a subdirectory of an svn repo a couple weeks ago.  I tried to pull in changes from the svn repo and got the following:

```
$ git svn fetch
    M   data/tree.js
Author: merger not defined in /Users/astacy/work/static_authors file

$ git svn rebase 
Index mismatch: 0415f543471e6a8f9b3ec787020bbe395c44d4f4 != a6767586c9e4f74cd279b0b42cc2545eac190704
rereading 76a26e5c064f05d26fa51aa2b2b715d50a7651b4
    M   data/tree.js
Author: merger not defined in /Users/astacy/work/static_authors file
```

`git status` says the working directory is clean, but the `data/tree.js` file is not updated in my git repo.  ***How do I pull this change in?***

#### more info:

I don't remember how I originally did the import, but I think it was something like:

```
$ git svn init <url>
```

`.git/config` has this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://astacy@example.com/var/svn/siq_repo
    fetch = my/path/to/directory/gloss:refs/remotes/trunk
[svn]
    authorsfile = /Users/astacy/work/static_authors
```

Also, the file in question, `data/tree.js` was moved immediately after the initial import to `src/data/tree.js`.

Answer (score 2):

`git svn rebase` seems to be picky about missing authors: It just stops rebasing. Add an entry for the user *merger* to the file */Users/astacy/work/static_authors* and you should be good to go:

Example: `merger = merger's name <mergers@emailadress>`

Comment: it's been too long since i did it to verify your answer, but that's for your input!